# Org-mode: add a deadline with minutes

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

In the quick capture window, I can add a deadline for 12pm today by typing `C-c C-d 12pm`:

```
** TODO test
DEADLINE: <2019-03-26 Tue 12:00>
```

If I add minutes with `12.30`, it moves the date to 2030:

```
** TODO test
DEADLINE: <2030-04-12 Fri>
```

and `12.30pm` is invalid.

Can I set minutes into a deadline in quick capture?

Comment: From what I've used, hours are written with colons, so you'd want to write `12:30`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minutes are separated from hours with colons rather than dots in org's date format. If you want to specify a hour, you want to write it as `12:30` rather than `12.30`, which would be confused for a day and a month or a month and a year (like in your case).